# how to fix a corrupted repo in GIT

Tags: git, bitbucket

My local git has got corrupted. How can I fix it. I tried to fix it by using `git pull` but got the following error

```
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/test_cases': unable to resolve reference 'refs/remotes/origin/test_cases': reference broken
From https://bitbucket.org/ManuChadha/codingjedi
 ! [new branch]      test_cases -> origin/test_cases  (unable to update local ref)
```

I ran `git fsck` and got the output

```
error: Invalid HEAD
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (2852/2852), done.
error: refs/heads/test_cases: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
error: refs/remotes/origin/test_cases: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
error: bad ref for .git/logs/HEAD
error: bad ref for .git/logs/refs/heads/test_cases
error: bad ref for .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/test_cases
dangling commit 0ea928e8d011907e77791327387d30a6ee591e1a
dangling commit f973890b94be93ca9edc753ed4091af0c29655ed
```

Comment: what if you delete only the ```test_cases``` branch locally and then pull?

Comment: got error `fatal: Failed to resolve HEAD as a valid ref.`

Comment: sorry, hard for me to reproduce. I guess you can't share the steps to corrupt the git repo, can you...?

Comment: sorry, can't I just deleted to previous one and created a new repo after saving latest changes. Fortunately, I had changed only one file!

Comment: Maybe it's the easiest and best solution in you case